# Using LINQ how can I check for an instance of a number in one array, in another array?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, contains

I have a list of `MyItem` objects called `myItems` like this:

```
public class MyItem{
    public int[] category_ids;
    public string name;
}

List<MyItem> myItems;
```

I want to filter down the list of objects with a list of selected categories so that the filtered list contains ANY of the filter category ids:

```
int[] filter = { 1, 5, 6, 9 };
```

How would I do that using LINQ in one line? (if its even possible, I cant wrap my head around it!)
I imagine something along the lines of:

```
IEnumerable<MyItem> filtered = myItems.Where(item => item.category_ids.Contains(xxx));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var filtered = myItems.Where(x => x.category_ids.Intersect(filter)
                                          .Any());
```

Answer (score 2):

Needs one more method call:

```
IEnumerable<MyItem> filtered = myItems.Where(item => item.category_ids.Any(x=>filter.Contains(x));
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option than the one already presented:

```
var filtered = myItems.Where( item => item.category_ids.Intersect( filter ).Count() > 0 );
```